# Creating a layout for a Formulary in latex

Tags: tikz-pgf, layout

I'm a beginner in LaTeX and I'm creating a formulary where for each formula or formulas there is a picture with the geometrical interpretation.

I have managed to create the graphical element that I want with the `tikz` package and the `tikzpicture` section plus the `\draw` and `\filldraw` commands.

I now have a picture and I would like to put the equations on the side; to do that I'm currently using a `node`,  but I'm not really that happy with the result, it's really verbose and ( probably ) semantically wrong; because I need a new paragraph, not a `node`.

Also there are things to consider:

- I will write a series of pictures + equations and only later worry about their layout
- I will not know how many columns is the optimal number of columns until I finish, it will depend on the largest picture / writing in the formulary probably

I would like to separate each picture + equation/s into a separate element, like a `<div>` or `<span>` in HTML.

So my questions are :

- there is such a *meta* element in Latex for the single row of picture + equations ?
- how to layout things in latex after the fact ?

EDIT:
here is a working example of the current results

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \tikzstyle help lines=[color=gray,thin]
    %\tikzstyle help lines+=[color=blue!50,very thick]
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2,cap=rect]
        % Local definitions
        \def\costhirty{0.8660256}
        % Colors
        \colorlet{anglecolor}{green!50!black}
        \colorlet{sincolor}{red}
        \colorlet{tancolor}{orange!80!black}
        \colorlet{coscolor}{blue}
        % Styles
        \tikzstyle{axes}=[]
        \tikzstyle{important line}=[very thick]
        \tikzstyle{information text}=[rounded corners,fill=red!10,inner sep=1ex]
        % The graphic
        \draw[style=help lines,step=0.5cm] (-1.4,-1.4) grid (1.4,1.4);
        \draw (0,0) circle (1cm);
        \begin{scope}[style=axes]
            \draw[->] (-1.5,0) -- (1.5,0) node[right] {$x$} coordinate(x axis);
            \draw[->] (0,-1.5) -- (0,1.5) node[above] {$y$} coordinate(y axis);
            \foreach \x/\xtext in {-1, -.5/-\frac{1}{2}, 1}
            \draw[xshift=\x cm] (0pt,1pt) -- (0pt,-1pt) node[below,fill=white] {$\xtext$};
            \foreach \y/\ytext in {-1, -.5/-\frac{1}{2}, .5/\frac{1}{2}, 1}
            \draw[yshift=\y cm] (1pt,0pt) -- (-1pt,0pt) node[left,fill=white] {$\ytext$};
        \end{scope}
        \filldraw[fill=green!20,draw=anglecolor] (0,0) -- (3mm,0pt) arc(0:30:3mm);
        \draw (15:2mm) node[anglecolor] {$\alpha$};
        \draw[style=important line,sincolor]
        (30:1cm) -- node[left=1pt,fill=white] {$\sin \alpha$} (30:1cm |- x axis);
        \draw[style=important line,coscolor]
        (30:1cm |- x axis) -- node[below=2pt,fill=white] {$\cos \alpha$} (0,0);
        \draw[style=important line,tancolor] (1,0) -- node[right=1pt,fill=white] {
            $\displaystyle \tan \alpha \color{black}=
            \frac{{\color{sincolor}\sin \alpha}}{\color{coscolor}\cos \alpha}$}
        (intersection of 0,0--30:1cm and 1,0--1,1) coordinate (t);
        \draw (0,0) -- (t);
        \draw[xshift=1.85cm]
        node[right,text width=6cm,style=information text]
        {
            The {\color{anglecolor} angle $\alpha$} is $30^\circ$ in the
            example ($\pi/6$ in radians). The {\color{sincolor}sine of
                $\alpha$}, which is the height of the red line, is
            \[
            {\color{sincolor} \sin \alpha} = 1/2.
            \]
            By the Theorem of Pythagoras ...
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2,cap=rect]
        % Local definitions
        \def\costhirty{0.8660256}
        % Colors
        \colorlet{anglecolor}{green!50!black}
        \colorlet{sincolor}{red}
        \colorlet{tancolor}{orange!80!black}
        \colorlet{coscolor}{blue}
        % Styles
        \tikzstyle{axes}=[]
        \tikzstyle{important line}=[very thick]
        \tikzstyle{information text}=[rounded corners,fill=red!10,inner sep=1ex]
        % The graphic
        \draw[style=help lines,step=0.5cm] (-1.4,-1.4) grid (1.4,1.4);
        \draw (0,0) circle (1cm);
        \begin{scope}[style=axes]
            \draw[->] (-1.5,0) -- (1.5,0) node[right] {$x$} coordinate(x axis);
            \draw[->] (0,-1.5) -- (0,1.5) node[above] {$y$} coordinate(y axis);
            \foreach \x/\xtext in {-1, -.5/-\frac{1}{2}, 1}
            \draw[xshift=\x cm] (0pt,1pt) -- (0pt,-1pt) node[below,fill=white] {$\xtext$};
            \foreach \y/\ytext in {-1, -.5/-\frac{1}{2}, .5/\frac{1}{2}, 1}
            \draw[yshift=\y cm] (1pt,0pt) -- (-1pt,0pt) node[left,fill=white] {$\ytext$};
        \end{scope}
        \filldraw[fill=green!20,draw=anglecolor] (0,0) -- (3mm,0pt) arc(0:30:3mm);
        \draw (15:2mm) node[anglecolor] {$\alpha$};
        \draw[style=important line,sincolor]
        (30:1cm) -- node[left=1pt,fill=white] {$\sin \alpha$} (30:1cm |- x axis);
        \draw[style=important line,coscolor]
        (30:1cm |- x axis) -- node[below=2pt,fill=white] {$\cos \alpha$} (0,0);
        \draw[style=important line,tancolor] (1,0) -- node[right=1pt,fill=white] {
            $\displaystyle \tan \alpha \color{black}=
            \frac{{\color{sincolor}\sin \alpha}}{\color{coscolor}\cos \alpha}$}
        (intersection of 0,0--30:1cm and 1,0--1,1) coordinate (t);
        \draw (0,0) -- (t);
        \draw[xshift=1.85cm]
        node[right,text width=6cm,style=information text]
        {
            The {\color{anglecolor} angle $\alpha$} is $30^\circ$ in the
            example ($\pi/6$ in radians). The {\color{sincolor}sine of
                $\alpha$}, which is the height of the red line, is
            \[
            {\color{sincolor} \sin \alpha} = 1/2.
            \]
            By the Theorem of Pythagoras ...
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2,cap=rect]
        % Local definitions
        \def\costhirty{0.8660256}
        % Colors
        \colorlet{anglecolor}{green!50!black}
        \colorlet{sincolor}{red}
        \colorlet{tancolor}{orange!80!black}
        \colorlet{coscolor}{blue}
        % Styles
        \tikzstyle{axes}=[]
        \tikzstyle{important line}=[very thick]
        \tikzstyle{information text}=[rounded corners,fill=red!10,inner sep=1ex]
        % The graphic
        \draw[style=help lines,step=0.5cm] (-1.4,-1.4) grid (1.4,1.4);
        \draw (0,0) circle (1cm);
        \begin{scope}[style=axes]
            \draw[->] (-1.5,0) -- (1.5,0) node[right] {$x$} coordinate(x axis);
            \draw[->] (0,-1.5) -- (0,1.5) node[above] {$y$} coordinate(y axis);
            \foreach \x/\xtext in {-1, -.5/-\frac{1}{2}, 1}
            \draw[xshift=\x cm] (0pt,1pt) -- (0pt,-1pt) node[below,fill=white] {$\xtext$};
            \foreach \y/\ytext in {-1, -.5/-\frac{1}{2}, .5/\frac{1}{2}, 1}
            \draw[yshift=\y cm] (1pt,0pt) -- (-1pt,0pt) node[left,fill=white] {$\ytext$};
        \end{scope}
        \filldraw[fill=green!20,draw=anglecolor] (0,0) -- (3mm,0pt) arc(0:30:3mm);
        \draw (15:2mm) node[anglecolor] {$\alpha$};
        \draw[style=important line,sincolor]
        (30:1cm) -- node[left=1pt,fill=white] {$\sin \alpha$} (30:1cm |- x axis);
        \draw[style=important line,coscolor]
        (30:1cm |- x axis) -- node[below=2pt,fill=white] {$\cos \alpha$} (0,0);
        \draw[style=important line,tancolor] (1,0) -- node[right=1pt,fill=white] {
            $\displaystyle \tan \alpha \color{black}=
            \frac{{\color{sincolor}\sin \alpha}}{\color{coscolor}\cos \alpha}$}
        (intersection of 0,0--30:1cm and 1,0--1,1) coordinate (t);
        \draw (0,0) -- (t);
        \draw[xshift=1.85cm]
        node[right,text width=6cm,style=information text]
        {
            The {\color{anglecolor} angle $\alpha$} is $30^\circ$ in the
            example ($\pi/6$ in radians). The {\color{sincolor}sine of
                $\alpha$}, which is the height of the red line, is
            \[
            {\color{sincolor} \sin \alpha} = 1/2.
            \]
            By the Theorem of Pythagoras ...
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Please share what you already wrote so users can have something to start helping you.

Comment: @SebGlav thanks, I have added a working example

Comment: Your question is simple but complex. I think that you should know a bit more about the final layout before trying to make a new environment to contain your pictures and descritptions. Anyway, what you're trying to achive could be made with `minipage`s. You could then put your Ti*k*Z picture alongside with math formulas.

Comment: @SebGlav ok, do you have some external reference with examples or something I can take a look at ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first need to find the right abstraction of what you need to do. Essentially you creating a database of equations with images or without.

1. Create the datastructure (a clist is fine) to hold the values.
2. Add the records to the DB.
3. Map over the clist and render the equations using an appropriate function.

```
    \documentclass{report}
        \usepackage{tikz}
        \ExplSyntaxOn
        \clist_new:N \l_my_formulary_clist
        
        \NewDocumentCommand\AddToEquationDB{m +m}
         {
           \cs_gset:cpn {#1}{#2}
           \clist_put_right:Nn \l_my_formulary_clist {\csname#1\endcsname}
         }
        

    
    \NewDocumentCommand\RenderEquations{ }
         {
           \clist_map_inline:Nn \l_my_formulary_clist {\[##1\]}
         }
        
        \ExplSyntaxOff
        
        \begin{document}
        \AddToEquationDB{quadratic} 
          {
            ax^2 + bx + c =0
          }
        \AddToEquationDB {linear}    
          {
            x = \frac{b}{a}
          }
        \AddToEquationDB{cubic}    
          {
            x^3 + 2x^2 + 10x = 20
          }
          
        
        \AddToEquationDB{pythagoras}{
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2,cap=rect]
                % Local definitions
                \def\costhirty{0.8660256}
                % Colors
                \colorlet{anglecolor}{green!50!black}
                \colorlet{sincolor}{red}
                \colorlet{tancolor}{orange!80!black}
                \colorlet{coscolor}{blue}
                % Styles
                \tikzstyle{axes}=[]
                \tikzstyle{important line}=[very thick]
                \tikzstyle{information text}=[rounded corners,fill=red!10,inner sep=1ex]
                % The graphic
                \draw[style=help lines,step=0.5cm] (-1.4,-1.4) grid (1.4,1.4);
                \draw (0,0) circle (1cm);
                \begin{scope}[style=axes]
                    \draw[->] (-1.5,0) -- (1.5,0) node[right] {$x$} coordinate(x axis);
                    \draw[->] (0,-1.5) -- (0,1.5) node[above] {$y$} coordinate(y axis);
                    \foreach \x/\xtext in {-1, -.5/-\frac{1}{2}, 1}
                    \draw[xshift=\x cm] (0pt,1pt) -- (0pt,-1pt) node[below,fill=white] {$\xtext$};
                    \foreach \y/\ytext in {-1, -.5/-\frac{1}{2}, .5/\frac{1}{2}, 1}
                    \draw[yshift=\y cm] (1pt,0pt) -- (-1pt,0pt) node[left,fill=white] {$\ytext$};
                \end{scope}
                \filldraw[fill=green!20,draw=anglecolor] (0,0) -- (3mm,0pt) arc(0:30:3mm);
                \draw (15:2mm) node[anglecolor] {$\alpha$};
                \draw[style=important line,sincolor]
                (30:1cm) -- node[left=1pt,fill=white] {$\sin \alpha$} (30:1cm |- x axis);
                \draw[style=important line,coscolor]
                (30:1cm |- x axis) -- node[below=2pt,fill=white] {$\cos \alpha$} (0,0);
                \draw[style=important line,tancolor] (1,0) -- node[right=1pt,fill=white] {
                    $\displaystyle \tan \alpha \color{black}=
                    \frac{{\color{sincolor}\sin \alpha}}{\color{coscolor}\cos \alpha}$}
                (intersection of 0,0--30:1cm and 1,0--1,1) coordinate (t);
                \draw (0,0) -- (t);
                \draw[xshift=1.85cm]
                node[right,text width=6cm,style=information text]
                {
                    The {\color{anglecolor} angle $\alpha$} is $30^\circ$ in the
                    example ($\pi/6$ in radians). The {\color{sincolor}sine of
                        $\alpha$}, which is the height of the red line, is
                    \[
                    {\color{sincolor} \sin \alpha} = 1/2.
                    \]
                    By the Theorem of Pythagoras ...
                };
            \end{tikzpicture}
        }
        
        
        \RenderEquations
            
        \end{document}
```